# C# How can I get a sum of 3 columns in a datagrid view with a loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to get a running total for 3 columns in my datatable. I need to be able to add the columns "Ceiling", "Floor" and "Fantasy Points" to get an Total in the "Average" Column for each individual row. I attempted a for loop but was unsuccessful as it will sum all 3 columns data for all rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        decimal sumfp = csv_datagridview.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Value));

        decimal sumfl = csv_datagridview.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[6].Value));

        decimal sumcl = csv_datagridview.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[5].Value));

        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in csv_datatable.Rows)
        {
            sum += (sumfp + sumfl + sumcl);
        }
        csv_datatable.Rows[0]["Average"] = sum;
```

[image]

Comment: You could use an expression on the underlying datatable and not have to loop thru the ui control at all  [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It will act on the *data*, not the view and be automatic

Comment: You can do something like this.  While looping through data set    set csv_datatable.Rows[0]["Average"] = row.Cells[5].Value +row.Cells[6].Value + row.Cells[7].Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in csv_datagridview.Rows)
    {
        decimal sumfp = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Value);
        decimal sumfl = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[6].Value);
        decimal sumcl = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[5].Value);

        decimal average= (sumfp + sumfl + sumcl) / 3m;
        row.Cells[8].Value= average;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt i need to utilize datagridviewrow rather then gridview?

Comment: That was it ! Thank you so much!